# Android - Single data request class that handle a lot of activity

Tags: java, android, json, server, android-volley

Im new to android and just learning how to pass data from server using json and volley.

what i want to ask is:

if i have a lot of activities on my apps, and each of every activity need to take data from the server, and I need to use json in every single class, and put the requeststring in it, which is very redundant.

Is there a way to put all the functions in just 1 class (maybe static), so I will have 1 class that only handling the data request from the client to the server. I found it really confusing, because at the same time, I need to modify the UI when the apps received the data (eg. move to another activity, or just simple change the textview).

So, basically the class will check whether the data exist on the database, if not, it will request the data from the server, and return it to the activity
it is possible to do this? Is there any tutorial that I can refer to?

Thanks a lot! cheers!

Comment: As you said, you should create a static class (ex. `ApiManager`), and implement your requests there and simply return the responses. (different method for each request). Also you could make your own `Response` object to wrap your data. By doing this, you can call your requests from anywhere.

Comment: which one is better, create a static class, implement all the requests there, or create a interface and implement the get the request on the activity class?

Comment: You should put your requests in a separate class, but yes, you could pass your activity to the request methods as an interface, then you call your callback when the response is ready. Regarding to my previous comment, I need to mention that, you cannot simply return the response, because all the requests are asynchronous, but you can use simply Otto or EventBus to get your callback on your activity.